# Angular 2 Typescript reload components on login/logout

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently, if I'm logged in as an admin, I have an admin section on my navigation component. If I logout, and login with a non-admin user, the admin section is still visible in the my side-nav). If I do a hard-refresh or `Location.reload()`, it goes away. I'd rather reload the side-nav component without refreshing the page. How do I go about reloading a component other than the component in which the `login()` and `logout()` functions is located?

**topnav.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-top-nav"
  //...
})

//...
login() {
    //do login stuff
  },
  error => {
    //do error stuff
  },
  () => {
    this.router.navigate(["/dashboard"]);
  });
}

logout() {
  //do logout stuff...
  this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
}
```

**topnav.component.html**

```
<form *ngIf="!loggedIn()" #loginForm="ngForm" class="navbar-form navbar-right" (ngSubmit)="login()">
  //login form
</form>

<a (click)="logout()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</a> //only present when logged in
```

**sidenav.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-side-nav"
  //...
})

export class SideNavComponent implements OnInit {
  //...
}
```

**sidenav.component.html**

```
//...
<ul class='nav navbar-nav' *ngIf="user.userRoleId == UserRoles.Admin">
```

Comment: Why dont you just run detection check run ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your `user` var looks like, if its component-bound then thats your problem. You'd want to move it to a service and update/set it when you login.